# Datatables - Add new column to row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this `data`

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'first',
    desc: 'mini desc'
  }, 
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'second',
    desc: 'mini desc'
  }
]
```

If i create datatable with this data i get this

> ```
> +----+--------+-------------+
> + ID + Name   + Description +
> +----+--------+-------------+
> + 1  + first  + mini desc   +
> +----+--------+-------------+
> + 2  + second + mini desc   +
> +----+------+---------------+
> ```

But i want result like this

> ```
> +---+----+--------+-------------+
> + * + ID + Name   + Description +
> +---+----+--------+-------------+
> + * + 1  + first  + mini desc   +
> +---+----+--------+-------------+
> + * + 2  + second + mini desc   +
> +---+----+--------+-------------+
>
> * - checkbox input
> ```

I know, that i can do it with replace data of column, but i want save all columns

```
createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
    $('td', row).eq(0).html('<input type="checkbox">')
}
```

How i can do it without replace data column ? Thanks.

Comment: Use `.prepend()` http://api.jquery.com/prepend/.

Comment: @Jason, yes i can use it, but i want have access to `row, data, index` vars like in my example.

Comment: What about `$('td', row).eq(0).before('<td><input type="checkbox"></td>');`?

Comment: Hmm... Yes, this work, but i can not use the sorting and other functional for this column...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `mRender` functionality in the `aoColums` definition:

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "data": dataset,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": 'id',
        "sWidth": "15px",
        "mRender": function(cell_data, type, full) {
            if (type === 'display') {
                return '<input id="check_' + cell_data + '" type="checkbox">';
            }
            return cell_data;
        }
    }, {
        "mData": 'id',
    }, {
        "mData": 'name'
    }, {
        "mData": 'desc'
    }]
})
```

This way the data (id in this case) will stay intact and can be sorted, but will be displayed as a checkbox with `ID="check_###"`.

Note that this is valid for dataTables 1.10, older Versions need a slightly different syntax. Also I didn't find all of the required CSS files for this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGWBkSkRZ75l6pu8XH6p?p=preview).